# Templated explicit conversion operator

Tags: c++, templates

So, I have this template class for which I'm trying to write a generic conversion operator.
What I've come up with is this ( doesn't work: "Error - expected a qualified name after 'typename'" ):

```
template <typename T>
class object{
...
T internal;
...
template <typename U>
explicit operator typename decltype(
std::conditional< 
     std::is_convertible<T, U>::type , U, T>::type)()
{
return static_cast<std::conditional<std::is_convertible<T, U>::type ,U, T>::type>(internal);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible?

Comment: Do note that `std::is_convertible<T, T>` holds in a lot of situations.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do, actually?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find a solution of my own:

```
    template <typename U>
    explicit operator typename decltype(std::conditional< 
                                        std::is_convertible<T, U>::type , 
                                        U, 
                                        T>::type)::value_type ()

    {
        return static_cast<typename decltype(std::conditional< 
                        std::is_convertible<T, U>::type , 
                        U, 
                        T>::type)::value_type>(internal);
    }
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? `decltype` should not work there.

Comment: I believe that it does require a typename before `std::conditional<>::type` as that is dependent and not necessarily a type. Additionally, only a few types have a nested `value_type` type, which seems to indicate that your real problem differs from what you are asking. In the future consider asking the **real question** you want solved. This does not answer the question you made.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes gcc 4.7.0